# Inserting a Value without splice or push command

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am currently working on some code to insert user inputted variables into an array at a specified point **WITHOUT** using the **splice** or the **push** command. I decided to try to use a while command as that is what makes the most sense to me as I am very new to javascript. When I do try to display nothing comes up.

```js
var array = []; // Flobal array to hold array
var d = ""; // Global string for output 

function fillArray() {
  // call function to clear the display values
  clearDisplay();
  // simple loop hard coded to 100 to set array values
  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    array[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1);
  }
  // call function to display the array
  displayArray();
}

function clearDisplay() {
  //Global string d is used to hold display
  d = "";
  // The div element named output is used to display output
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "";
}

function displayArray() {
  // simple loop to add array values to string d
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
    d += i + ' : ' + array[i] + "<br/>";
  }
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = d;
}
//-------------------------------------------------------

//Scan array and insert into index
function insertArray() {
  var m = parseInt(document.getElementById("index").value);
  var n = parseInt(document.getElementById("value").value);

  while (i < m) {
    i++;
  }
  if (i == m) {
    array[i] == n;
  }
  displayArray();
}
```

Comment: _"WITHOUT using the splice or the push command"_ <- why?

Comment: @Phil OP explained already because "that is what makes the most sense to me"

Comment: Can you use `.slice()` and `concat()`?

Comment: @Wyck I thought that was OP's reasoning for using a `while` loop. They should explain what it is in particular about [`Array.prototype.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) that they don't understand?

Comment: "I am very new to java" Please remember, Java and Javascript are *not* the same...this is Javascript

Comment: Do you want to overwrite the previous value at that index, or do you want to keep all the values and move those with a higher index?

Comment: Could the problem be that you have not declared `i`.  `i` is undefined, so `i < m` is always false, and `i ==m` is also false and nothing ever gets inserted?

Comment: Please make clear what type of problem you want to solve. Reading this code indicates you just want to do array[m] = n

The loop is unnecessary overhead, you should instead check the boundaries of array if the index m is inside the range.

Comment: I apologize for the late response but the way I was seeing it that (i) would increase till it matched the m variable that the user inputs. As far as if I want to overwrite or keep moving I would like to keep it moving.  As for why no splice or push is for the sheer reason it hasnt been covered yet so was seeing for other ways to do it.

Comment: I figured it out  function insertIntoArray() {

  clearDisplay();
  //get value of index of value to insert
  var n = parseInt(document.getElementById("index").value);
  var v = parseInt(document.getElementById("value").value);
  var count = 0;
  
  d = "<br/> Inserting " + v + " at " + n + "<br/>";

//Big O notation would be n for this function as this is linear due to no subsets of loops
  for (i = array.length - 2; i >= n; i--) { 
    count++;
    array[i + 1] = array[i];
  }

  d = "<br/>You have done " + count + " operations.<br/>";
  array[n] = v;
  displayArray();

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to add elements to an array without using the splice or push command at the given index. See the implementation of insertArray function, I have commented out the wrong code and written a new line.

```js
var array = []; // Flobal array to hold array
var d = ""; // Global string for output 

function fillArray() {
  // call function to clear the display values
  clearDisplay();
  // simple loop hard coded to 100 to set array values
  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    array[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1);
  }
  // call function to display the array
  //displayArray();
}

function clearDisplay() {
  //Global string d is used to hold display
  d = "";
  // The div element named output is used to display output
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "";
}

function displayArray() {
  // simple loop to add array values to string d
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
    d += i + ' : ' + array[i] + " ";
  }
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = d;
}
//-------------------------------------------------------

//Scan array and insert into index
function insertArray() {

  var m = parseInt(document.getElementById("index").value);
  var n = parseInt(document.getElementById("value").value);
  
  var temp = array[m];
  array[m] = n;
  for (var i = m+1; i < 100; i++) {
    array[i] = temp;
    temp = array[i];
  }

/*
  while (i < m) {
    i++;
  }
  if (i == m) {
    array[i] = n;
  }
*/
displayArray();
}

fillArray();
```

```html
<p>Output: </p>
<input type="text" id="index">
<input type="text" id="value">
<button onClick="insertArray();">Insert</button>
<hr>
<div id="output">
</div>
```

Please let me know if this is what you wanted.

Comment: Your code is replacing value at specified index not adding

Comment: @ponury-kostek That's what the OP has been trying to do in his code. I've only tried to fix his code if that's what he wanted.

Comment: Is there a way to push the remaining values? BTW I appreciate the help

Comment: @Grunt_Worker can you please explain what do you mean by remaining values? You wish to add more items to the array apart from the given size? e.g currently the size of array is 100. do you want to add an item at the end of this array at index 100?

Comment: Here is what I am trying to accomplish array=[2,4,5,6] and say I am trying put a 3 on the second index so it would move integer over and remove the last integer in array so array=[2,3,4,5]. Is that a better way of saying it?

Comment: @Grunt_Worker I have edited my answer so to make it work as u described. I could not run it because using mobile right now. But I hope u get the idea. Please let me know if it doesn’t work.

Comment: Select my answer as your solution if it's what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution is to create new array every time and overwrite old one. We create two counters one for old array, second for new array. While coping items from old array to new one, when we'r at desired index we'r adding desired value from input and increases only new array counter.

```
function insertArray() {
    var m = parseInt(document.getElementById("index").value);
    var n = parseInt(document.getElementById("value").value);
    var c = 0, o = 0, l = array.length + 1, new_array = [];
    while (c < l) {
        if (c === m) {
            new_array[c] = n;
        } else {
            new_array[c] = array[o];
            o++;
        }
        c++;
    }
    array = new_array;
    clearDisplay();
    displayArray();
}
```

```js
var array = []; // Flobal array to hold array
var d = ""; // Global string for output
function fillArray() {
 // call function to clear the display values
 clearDisplay();
 // simple loop hard coded to 10 to set array values
 for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  array[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1);
 }
 // call function to display the array
 displayArray();
}

function clearDisplay() {
 //Global string d is used to hold display
 d = "";
 // The div element named output is used to display output
 document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "";
}

function displayArray() {
 // simple loop to add array values to string d
 for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  d += i + " : " + array[i] + "<br/>";
 }
 document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = d;
}
fillArray();
//-------------------------------------------------------
//Scan array and insert into index
function insertArray() {
 var m = parseInt(document.getElementById("index").value);
 var n = parseInt(document.getElementById("value").value);
 var c = 0, o = 0, l = array.length + 1, new_array = [];
 while (c < l) {
  if (c === m) {
   new_array[c] = n;
  } else {
    new_array[c] = array[o];
      o++;
    }
  c++;
 }
 array = new_array;
    clearDisplay();
 displayArray();
}
```

```html
<p>Output: </p>
<input type="text" id="index">
<input type="text" id="value">
<button onClick="insertArray();">Insert</button>
<hr>
<div id="output">
</div>
```